# get value from ascx user control to aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, user-controls

I have two files in my project. One is user control (popup) customerpicker.ascx and one is default.aspx page. In customerpicker I have dynamically generated gridview and 'select' column with SelectButton.

What I want is this: When I click on 'select' on random row in gridview, then I like to display value from selected row **immediately** (like ajax) to aspx.page. How it is possible?

There is part of my code in .ascx:

```
public string showOnaspx { get; set; }
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{

    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];
    showOnaspx = row.Cells[1].Text; 

    e.Cancel = true;
}

protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow; 
}
```

I tried casting, get/set methods, but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Spent another few hours on this, still no success.

Comment: This problem still bothering me. Any idea?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer on that question is pretty easy.. We can save variabile in session and then read it in aspx.page wherever we want.

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];
Session["sessionid"]= row.Cells[1].Text; 
e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Feeling so stupid right now, because I spent few days to figure it out simple way to do that.